# How to use route in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to use route in javascript but I get an error `Route [product.like + productid] not defined.` is there any way I can use route instead ?

Ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '{{ route('product.like'  productid) }}',
        data: {
            'user_id': userid,
            'product_id': productid,
        },
```

Route

```
  Route::post('product/like/{id}', ['as' => 'product.like', 'uses' => 'LikeController@likeProduct']);
```

Comment: I think you just need to use `"` instead of `'`: `url: "{{ route('product.like', $productid) }}",`, and as long as this `$.ajax()` call is within a `<script>` tag in a `.blade.php`, it should work ok. Oh, and `$productid` needs to be a php variable. If `productid` is a JS variable, this approach will not work.

Comment: how can I define `productid` because I get an error `Undefined variable: productid` @TimLewis

Comment: `$productid` can be passed from the controller function that handles this view as it should be defined as a URL parameter.

Comment: I have this button where I get the product id         `<a style="display: {{$product->isLiked ? "" : "none"}}" id="afavourite{{$product->id}}" onClick="AddFavourites({{$product->id}}, {{ Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : 0 }})" >` @TimLewis

Comment: Hmm ok, if you're doing it that way, then `$productid` won't be a PHP variable. Simply don't use the `route()` helper, just use a basic string: `url: '/product/like/' + productid'`, or use the `url()` helper: `url: "{{ url('/product/like/') }}" + productid`.

Comment: I was using the url but I had problem in some of my routes like in product detail if I click the like button url is like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/like/40?user_id=1&product_id=40` on console it says `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` that is why I asked the question @Tim Lewis

Comment: Well yeah, you can't navigate to a `POST` route like that. That's a separate issue though.

Comment: I was just confused why it saying `get method not supported` while I use POST in my route @TimLewis

Comment: Because if you navigate to that URL, that's a `GET` request. Submitting a form, or an AJAX call with the `method: "POST"` is a `POST` request. As for why you were getting that, it's likely you had an `href` to that route instead of an additional AJAX function, or similar.

Comment: So there is no way I can make it POST instead of get? @TimLewis

Comment: Read carefully: If you navigate to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/like/40` in your browser, that is a `GET` request, and there is no way to make that a `POST` request. You can only do a `POST` request via a `<form>` element (`method="POST"`) or an AJAX call (`method: "POST"`). So simply don't use `<a href="...">` and you're fine. If you need more clarification on that, ask a new question; we're getting off-topic here.

Comment: oh thank you @TimLewis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the route helper with string placeholders and then replace the placeholder with javascript variables.

```js
function AddFavourites(productid, userid) {
    let url = "{{ route('product.like', ['id' => ':id']) }}".replace(':id', productid);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: {
            'user_id': userid,
        },
    }).done(function(response, status){
        //
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //
    });
}
```